# Change input filename according to ticker

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories

I want to import a series of files with similar filenames that change according to a "ticker". An example is filenames `A1_data.dat`, `B2_data.dat`, `C3_data.dat` etc. The ticker is a list of text values `ticker={"A1","B2","C3"}`

The following line of code works fine, for the appropriate file path (all files are in the same folder).

```
ticker = {"A1", "B2", "C3"};
Table[Import[FileNameJoin[{"C:\\Users\\Cartman\\Desktop\\data", 
StringReplace["ticker_data.dat", "ticker" -> ticker[[i]]]}], "Table"], {i, 1, 3}]
```

However, I was wondering how this can be written without a loop structure such as `Table` or `Do` but by setting an appropriate function and using e.g. `Map`. The idea is to change the ticker part of the file path in `Import`

```
"C:\\Users\\Cartman\\Desktop\\data\\TICKER_data.dat"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe overkill for this example, but there is `StringTemplate` which I think is made exactly for such use cases:

```
template = StringTemplate[
   "C:\\Users\\Cartman\\Desktop\\data\\`Ticker`_data.dat"]
```

then replacing the `` `Ticker` `` part will be done like this:

```
TemplateApply[template, <|"Ticker" -> "A12"|>]
```

You can use this in any loop like contruct like e.g.:

```
ticker={"A1","B2","C3"};
Map[TemplateApply[template,<|"Ticker"->#|>]&,ticker]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is closer to my idea because Ican replace `Map` with `MapAt` for a specific ticker.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this properly, but I think this might work for you:

```
ticker = {"A1", "B2", "C3"};
mydata = Import["C:\\Users\\Cartman\\Desktop\\data\\"<> # <>"_data.dat", "Table"]&/@ticker
```

This should do exactly what you have written above. The `#` acts as a placeholder for something to be slotted in later, the `&` tells it to slot in whatever comes after, and `/@` is just `Map` like you suggested. The `<>` is for joining strings.

`mydata` should now contain 3 tables. One caveat is that if you ever have to import a single file using this method, the `/@` will cause there to be an extra layer of brackets, so `mydata[[1]]` is the actual table.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is close to what I described but I would also like to use `MapAt` or a structure like `f[ticker_]:=Import[blahblahblah\ticker]`

Comment: You can easily replace my `Map` with `MapAt` if that's what you prefer. `mydata = MapAt[Import["C:\\Users\\Cartman\\Desktop\\data\\"<> # <>"_data.dat", "Table"]&, ticker, All]` where `All` can be replaced with whatever specification you want `MapAt` to have. If you'd prefer some kind of function, then `f[ticker_]:=Import["blahblahblah\\"<> ticker <>"_data.dat"]`.